# Найти расстояние между отрезками

Tags: c++

Отрезки могут быть горизонтальные или вертикальные. У меня есть верхняя точка отрезка(если он вертикальный) и левая(если он горизонтальный) и длина отрезка.
Как найти кратчайшее расстояние между ними?

Отрезки (их количество именно 2) могут располагаться как угодно: оба вертикальные; оба горизонтальные; один горизонтальный, другой вертикальный; могут пересекаться; могут не пересекаться.
Пример входных данных:
1) Горизонтальный, х = 100, у = 100, l = 50,
2) Вертикальный, x = 50, y = 250, l = 150;

Comment: Несовсем понятно: у тебя данны два отрезка, один из которых горизонтальный, а другой вертикальный? Или данны просто два отрезка, но ты не знаешь какие они? Покажи конкретно входные данные.

Comment: > между ними

То есть у вас два отрезка?

Comment: Найдите проекции отрезков на оси координат. Каждый отрезок даст проекцию в виде точки на одну ось и в виде отрезка на другую. Если проекции могут перекрываться только по одной оси, по обеим или не перекрываться, это даст информацию о кратчайшем расстоянии (Пифагор в помощь в последнем случае). Это логика. Любая задача начинается с анализа.